# Improved SharePoint/MOSS 2007 Wiki

Tags: sharepoint, wiki

We use SharePoint (MOSS 2007) for storing all of our internal documents, and it works great as a document management system.  One of the problems we have though is using the Wiki feature of SharePoint.  For the most part, it is lacking the general features that make using a Wiki worthwhile.  As a result, we have had several departments just setup ad-hoc MediaWiki servers instead of using SharePoint's built-in functionality.

Are there any third-party add-ons to SharePoint to replace or improve the Wiki?  What will SharePoint 2010 bring for improvements in this area?

Some of the features we are looking for are:

- The ability to easily insert images while editing a document
- Attach files to a page or inline
- Improved markup (similar to MediaWiki)
- Navigation and/or table of contents
- Orphaned/Requested page lists

Comment: Great feedback. I'm responsible for the next version of SharePoint wikis - feel free to contact me directly: kevin.davis@microsoft.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything in the press or on MS's site for improved wiki in the upcoming version.

Google result showed several add-ons. Here is one:

http://www.kwizcom.com/ProductPage.asp?ProductID=524&ProductSubNodeID=525

Comment: That seems to have the features I am looking for and would be less than half the cost of Confluence with the connector.

Answer (score 4):

I would check out Community Kit for SharePoint Enhanced Wiki Edition

http://cks.codeplex.com/Wiki/View.aspx?title=Enhanced%20Wiki%20Edition

Community Kit for SharePoint is a set of free features worked on by mostly SharePoint MVP's so you know the free code your getting is solid.  The aim of the project is to fix the shortcomings of a few areas of SharePoint, such as Wikis and Blogs.  I have personally used the Blog edition and have nothing but great things to say about it.

Comment: That looks promising, but is missing some of the features we are looking for (I edited the question).

Comment: I was really excited about the CKS:EWE, but it looks like it's lost steam. If anyone is interested in picking up the torch let me know..

Comment: Since SharePoint 2010 is around the corner, I believe the makers of CKS are focusing their attention to the next version, so I'm guessing that there won't be too much new coming from the CKS project other than bug fixes

Answer (score 2):

If money isn't an object I can highly recommend using [Confluence Wiki](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) with [Sharepoint Connector (for Confluence)](http://www.atlassian.com/sharepoint/).

Answer (score 1):

If you have input on the next version of SharePoint's Wiki you should let Kevin Davis know, http://twitter.com/spwiki He has been seeking input for a while now, and if you're a heavy user, I'm sure you could provide some valuable insight.

Answer (score 1):

Improvements to SharePoint vNext including wikis will be unveiled at the SharePoint conference in October.

http://www.mssharepointconference.com/Pages/default.aspx

Stay tuned!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [SharePoint Wiki Plus](http://www.kwizcom.com/ProductPage.asp?ProductID=524&ProductSubNodeID=525) from KWizCom.

Cheers,

Henrico